# Caching won't work in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsurlrequestcachepolicy

I have a website which can be used offline too. I have created an app which use `UIWebView` and I said that my `UIWebView` should cache this site with the following code

```
[self setRequestObj:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:loadUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0]];
```

If I started my app the first time with internet connection my `console` logged

```
2016-08-24 15:37:01.713 BrowserApp[1991:345138] applicationDidBecomeActive!
2016-08-24 15:37:01.955 BrowserApp[1991:345138] NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
2016-08-24 15:37:22.003 BrowserApp[1991:345138] applicationDidEnterBackground!
2016-08-24 15:37:22.559 BrowserApp[1991:345138] applicationWillEnterForeground!
2016-08-24 15:37:23.075 BrowserApp[1991:345138] applicationDidBecomeActive!
2016-08-24 15:37:37.069 BrowserApp[1991:345138] applicationDidEnterBackground!
2016-08-24 15:37:37.073 BrowserApp[1991:345138] applicationWillTerminate!
```

I see that every method is called in the file `AppDelegate.m`. I disconnect my phone from the internet, launch my app again (wasn't in the background like my `console` told) and nothing happens. I only get a white website.

Why the `website` wouldn't be displayed on my screen although I set to `cache` it?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the page you have loaded has an expiration date (it may be set to expire immediately). Try with the cahce policy set as `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad` (although that might not be good in the long term, because it will *never* reload).

Alternatively, (more probably) the response headers from the website may contain a cache-control header. Regardless of what you say, the page can still tell NSURLRequest that it should not be cached.

To investigate, you could set a breakpoint or put some logging in your code where you handle did receive response. Cast the `NSURLResponse` to an `NSHTTPURLResponse` and then look at the headers using `allHeaderFields`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug with URLCache. When I kill the app, put the phone in airplane mode and relaunch the app, the `WebViewDelegate`'s `didFailLoadWithError` gets called even though the response is cached.

Also the `URLCache.shared.cachedResponse(for: urlRequest)` doesn't return a `CachedURLResponse`.

I also checked the Cache.db and it was containing the saved responses and assets.

Wierd!